# List records in table and on click display details in form

Tags: views, routes, forms

I created a website which has two menus in it. One is to enter details of a person and the other to view list of entered persons. Here is the code

```
function agents_menu(){
  $items=array();
  $items['enquirylist']=array(
    'title'=>'View Enquiries',
    'description'=>'Lists all the enquiries',
    'page callback'=>'show_enquirylist', 
    'access callback'=>TRUE,
    'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
    'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['enquiryform']=array(
    'title'=>'New Enquiry',
    'description'=>'Add new enquiries form',
    'page callback'=>'agents_form', 
    'access callback'=>TRUE,
    'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
    'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['enquiry_details']=array(
    'page callback'=>'run_enquiry_details',
    'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
    'access callback'=>TRUE,
    'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function enquiries_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form = array();
  $form['#theme'] = 'enquiries';
  $form['efname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'First Name',
    '#size' => 28,
    '#maxlength' => 100,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['elname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Last Name',
    '#size' => 28,
    '#maxlength' => 100,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['edob'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => 'Date of Birth',
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $options = array('0'=>'Male','1'=>'Female');
  $selected = '0';
  $form['egender'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Choose Gender"),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $selected,
  );
  $form['edob'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Date of Birth',
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
  $form['submit_btn'] = array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value'=>'Submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function show_enquirylist(){
  $header=array(
    array('data'=>t('Name'), 'field'=>'efname', 'sort'=>'asec'),
    array('data'=>t('Phone')),
    array('data'=>t('Email')),
  );
  $query = db_select('enquiries','u');
  $query->fields('u', array('eid','efname','elname','eemail','emobile',));
  $table_sort = $query->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header);
  $pager = $table_sort->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(5);
  $result = $pager->execute();

  $rows = array();
  foreach($result as $res){
    $rows[] = array(l($res->efname.' '.$res->elname, "enquiry_details",array('query'=>array('vars'=>$res->eid))),$res->emobile,$res->eemail,);
  }
  $output = '';
  if(!empty($rows)){
    $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows'=>$rows, 'attributes'=> array('id'=>'sort-table')));
  $output .= theme('pager');
  }
  else {
    $output .= t("No results found");
  }
  return $output;
}

function run_enquiry_details($form, &$form_state){
  $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {enquiries} WHERE eid='".$_GET['vars']."'");
  $form = drupal_get_form('enquiries_form');
  foreach($query AS $result){
    $form['efname']['#value']=t($result->efname);
    $form['efname']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    $form['efname']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'readonly';

    $form['elname']['#value']=t($result->elname);
    $form['elname']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    $form['elname']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'readonly';
  }
  return $form;
}

function agents_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if(isset($_GET['vars'])){
    $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {enquiries} WHERE eid='".$_GET['vars']."'");
    foreach($query as $result){
      $form['egender']['#default_value'] = t($result->egender);
      $form['egender']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
      $form['egender']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'readonly';

      $dob = getdate(strtotime($result->edob));
      $form['edob']['#value']['day'] = strval($dob[mday]);
      $form['edob']['#value']['month'] = strval($dob[mon]);
      $form['edob']['#value']['year'] = strval($dob[year]);
      $form['edob']['day']['#value']= strval($dob[mday]);
      $form['edob']['month']['#value']= strval($dob[mon]);
      $form['edob']['year']['#value']= strval($dob[year]);

      $form['submit_btn']['#access']=FALSE;
      $form['eimage']['#access']=FALSE;
    }
    return $form;
  }
}
```

If I don't use $_GET['vars'], the form is working fine. I can add details and submit into the database without any issues. Viewing the list of persons is absolutely working fine and when I click on the user name, it is calling enquiry_details with vars= id number. But to set the date, I used hook_form_alter to update the date of birth values. Without hook_form_alter, it is not updating the values of date and gender. Can someone guide me how to attain this without any obstacles?

Comment: There are so many issues with the code that I don't know where to being. Worst is that you have SQL Injection vulnerabilities making it possible for attackers to delete your entire database.